# The foreign key has value, but do not shows up in template

Tags: django

This code is the templates html:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in hosts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.nid}}</td>
        <td>{{row.hostname}}</td>
        <td>{{row.ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.port}}</td>
        <td>{{row.bussiness_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.bussiness.caption}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`bussiness_ip` is a foreign key of the host table, and in the sqlite3 it has value:

[image]

But the `row.bussiness_ip` did not shows up, nor the `row.bussiness.ip` in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td>{{row.bussiness_id}}</td>
```

should be the name as thats what defined in the database

or

```
<td>{{ row.bussiness.id }}</td>
```

as its a foreign key and i hope you have declared as

```
business = models.ForeignKey(modelname)
```

Comment: I take mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: a typo!

In you database, the field is called `business_id` and in your template it is called `business_ip`.

Try this:

```
 {{ row.bussiness_id }}
```

Hope it helps!